# C - error: storage size of ‘a’ isn’t known

Tags: c, gcc, struct

This is my C program...

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct xyx {
    int x;
    int y;
    char c;
    char str[20];
    int arr[2];
};

int main(void)
{
    struct xyz a;
    a.x = 100;
    printf("%d\n", a.x);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the error that I am getting....

Press ENTER or type command to continue

```
13structtest.c: In function ‘main’:
13structtest.c:13:13: error: storage size of ‘a’ isn’t known
13structtest.c:13:13: warning: unused variable ‘a’ [-Wunused-variable]
```

Comment: Instead of the rather cryptic error GCC gives, I prefer MSVC's: `error C2079: 'a' uses undefined struct 'xyz'`

Comment: feel like an idiot !! thanks :)

Comment: I suggest this be tagged as `gcc` since this is a compiler specific question

Answer (score 34):

Your struct is called `struct xyx` but `a` is of type `struct xyz`. [Once you fix that, the output is `100`](http://codepad.org/keoi4StZ).

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct xyx {
    int x;
    int y;
    char c;
    char str[20];
    int arr[2];
};

int main(void)
{
    struct xyx a;
    a.x = 100;
    printf("%d\n", a.x);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

To anyone with who is having this problem, its a typo error. Check your spelling of your struct delcerations and your struct

Answer (score 12):

In this case the user has done mistake in definition and its usage.
If someone has done a `typedef` to a structure the same should be used without using `struct` following is the example.

```
typedef struct
{
   int a;
}studyT;
```

When using in a function

```
int main()
{
   struct studyT study; // This will give above error.
   studyT stud; // This will eliminate the above error.
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

you define the struct as xyx but you're trying to create the struct called xyz.

Answer (score 4):

Say it like this: `struct xyx a;`

Answer (score 4):

correct typo of

```
struct xyz a;
```

to

```
struct xyx a;
```

Better you can try typedef, easy to b

Answer (score 3):

You define your struct as `xyx`, however in your main, you use `struct xyz a;`
, which only creates a forward declaration of a differently named struct.

Try using `xyx a;` instead of that line.

Comment: It fails to create a forward declaration; it would succeed with `struct xyz *pa;`, but as it is, it fails because the size of `a` (aka `struct xyz`) is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

I solved mine by correcting a simple error in my code.
`list_t new_end_code` declaration brought the error.
It should be,

```
list_t *new_end_code
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare the structs before the main function.
2. Fix the spelling mistake of that variable name if any e