# Why am I getting error: storage size of ‘st1’ isn’t known

Tags: c, debugging, struct, size, storage

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    struct info st1, st2;
    printf("Enter Quiz1: ");
    scanf("%f",&st1.quiz1);
    printf("Enter Quiz2: ");
    scanf("%f",&st1.quiz2); //print out quiz1 and quiz2 values for st1
    printf("The values for Quiz1:%f\n",st1);
    printf("The values for Quiz2:%f\n",st1);
}
```

---

Comment: Because you have not told the compiler what `struct info` is. Where is that defined?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  struct info st1, st2;
  printf("Enter Quiz1: ");
  scanf("%f",&st1.quiz1);
  printf("Enter Quiz2: ");
  scanf("%f",&st1.quiz2);
  printf("The values for Quiz1:%f\n",st1);
  printf("The values for Quiz2:%f\n",st1);
}
```

look at [C - error: storage size of ‘a’ isn’t known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798761/c-error-storage-size-of-a-isn-t-known)

You should include the headers from module file or specify the type before declaration of any variable of this type.

https://godbolt.org/z/hb1v4xePs

```
Output of x86-64 gcc 9.2 (Compiler #1) <source>: In function 'int main()': <source>:4:13: error: aggregate 'main()::info st1' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
    4 | struct info st1, st2;
      |             ^~~ <source>:4:18: error: aggregate 'main()::info st2' has incomplete type and cannot be defined
    4 | struct info st1, st2;
      |                  ^~~
```

https://godbolt.org/z/MenM7s86P
We fixed the code (it is compiling) but still needs improvements (not working as desired):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct info {
    float quiz1;
    float quiz2;
};

int main()
{
struct info st1, st2;
printf("Enter Quiz1: ");
scanf("%f",&st1.quiz1);
printf("Enter Quiz2: ");
scanf("%f",&st1.quiz2);
printf("The values for Quiz1:%f\n",st1);
printf("The values for Quiz2:%f\n",st1);
}
```

See that You printf st1 twice and not read st1.quiz(1|2) values. So I assume you wanted this:

https://godbolt.org/z/795dhjhcn

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct info {
    float quiz;
};

int main()
{
struct info st1, st2;
printf("Enter Quiz1: ");
scanf("%f",&st1.quiz);
printf("Enter Quiz2: ");
scanf("%f",&st2.quiz);
printf("The values for Quiz1:%f\n",st1.quiz);
printf("The values for Quiz2:%f\n",st2.quiz);
}
```

Comment: You should also check the return value of `scanf()`. Sidenote, code could benefit from better formatting.

Answer (score 0):

### Because you have not declared info (structure) . And you are trying to create two variables of type info .
To remove error first declare info.

```
#include <stdio.h>
// creating info data type
struct info{
   float quiz;
};


//Driver Code
int main(){   
    struct info st1, st2;
    printf("Enter Quiz1: ");
    scanf("%f",&st1.quiz);
    printf("Enter Quiz2: ");
    scanf("%f",&st2.quiz);
    printf("The values for Quiz1:%f\n",st1.quiz);
    printf("The values for Quiz2:%f\n",st2.quiz);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Instead of using st1.quiz1 and st2.quiz2. Use st1.quiz and st2.quiz . Because st1 and st2 are two different variables and they have their separate memory allocated in format as declared in struct info.